# Replace INDIRECT and ADDRESS volatile functions

Tags: excel-formula

I want to count non-empty cells in a Row of a table named "tblShiftTable" without #Headers.

I currently use the formula: `=COUNTA(INDIRECT( ADDRESS(@ROW(tblShiftTable),@COLUMN(tblShiftTable))):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(@ROW(tblShiftTable),@COLUMN(tblShiftTable)+COLUMNS(tblShiftTable)-1)))`

Could someone please suggest me a better solution with INDEX funcion?

Comment: Your formula seems to be counting the non-empty cells in the **first row** of the table.  Is that your intent?  If so, consider `=COUNTA(INDEX(tblShiftTable,1,))`

Comment: If you want it to count the total number of rows that contain data use something like `=Sumproduct(--(Mmult(--(tblShiftTable<>""),transpose(column(tblShiftTable))^0)>0))`

Comment: Is there a way to change the absolute reference to first row in your formula "=COUNTA(INDEX(tblShiftTable,1,))" so it can spill all the rows in the table or if this is not possible, just to deploy the formula to subsequent cells instead of changing the reference manual?

Comment: Now I see that you already have answered my second question. The formula =Sumproduct(--(Mmult(--(tblShiftTable<>""),transpose(column(tblShiftTable))^0)>0)) does the trick.
Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Actually the formula "Mmult(--(tblShiftTable<>""),transpose(column(tblShiftTable))^0)" does spill the result of all the rows.

Comment: Correct, I thought you wanted the count of rows not containing any data, but in the end it's basically the same logic